# Finding root cause for - Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies

Tags: .net, dll, visual-studio-2019

I have a VS2019 solution with about 150 legacy projects that no one knows much about 50% of the projects. I know exactly what dll its complaining about (its kinda of a Tracer). Looking for ways to fix this issue: I have read through many SO answers and I have run out of options. What else can I try?

I am kinda new to .net (just Entry level knowledge from years back)

**Debugging Efforts/Findings:**

- The solution as a whole shows Mixed platform in VS2019 but each project under it is a AnyCpu project. Not sure why but I assumed it might be because of the precompiled x86 dll references?
- The Dll missing is a precompiled one and no body has source code for it. Its in an x86 Folder and so I know its compiled for x86
- The entire solutions compiles without even a warning of any mismatched dlls.
- The executable code using that DLL runs fine on my Windows 10 (it breaks but not on that dll)
- The executable when on a server 2019 (I cannot install anything here to debug or trace) breaks complaining that this DLL is missing whiles it is there on the folder itself.
- I have checked (searched and verified each references path in VS2019) each of the projects that reference this DLL. Its all pointing to the same DLL (Except one project which was fixed and still producing same error)
- I have deleted the reference and re-added it and still doesnt work
- I have removed the reference in that particular project code and moved it to a initial part of the executable to force the error there and it errors out in the newly referenced project as expected. (Still no error on my windows 10)
- Now I removed this DLL from my Windows 10 and I get to simulate the same error as on my server
- I have deleted my bin folder and rebuilt and is still the same error
- I have closed and reopened my VS and clean and re built and its still the same.
- There are no App.config redirections anywhere for the dll.
- No IIS involved.
- The server is brand new
- I understand there is dependency walker but I already know which Dll it complaining about already.
- As I am compiling all projects in AnyCPU even if Dll is any x86 or x64 I assume it should run anywhere?
- I also checked the dll security . Nothing showing its blocked

what am I missing?

Even with FusionLogs I get same successfull message even on server but command prompt throws error on xyz.dll:

```
The operation was successful. 
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.


LOG: Assembly Name is: Xyz, Version=Xyz, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=Xyz 
LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from C:\Xyz.dll. 
LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context.
```

Comment: Maybe there is more dependencies missing? I mean the dll itself may have more dependencies. What is the target framework?

Comment: 4.7 and dependencies compiled are same for both Win10 and server